# django-tables2 linkColumn accessor

Tags: python, django, accessor, django-tables2

I have been using [django-tables2](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-tables2/latest/) which I like, but i run into some problems

I am trying to make a table in which cells link out to a different table, or an outside link
 the example in the documentation is :

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('people/(\d+)/', views.people_detail, name='people_detail')
)
```

**tables.py**

```
from django_tables.utils import A  # alias for Accessor

class PeopleTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.LinkColumn('people_detail', args=[A('pk')])
```

I have been trying to use this to no success...
What would be the view and template that would go with this example?
I think there might be a problem with the url but I am not sure what it is...
Can anyone explain:  `args=[A('pk')]`

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but thanks for posting about django-tables. I've been looking for something like this.

Comment: Hi I hope you've resolved the problem you were having, but if not can you please provide more details about what exactly was not working?

Answer (score 3):

`args=[A('pk')]` is the primary key of the model from which you're displaying the table. Your example would create a column 'Name' with the cell content `<a href="/people/pk"></a>` pk would be the primary key (number).
The view would be `views.people_detail` and the template would be whatever you've defined in this view...

Here's the link to the doc: [django-tables2 doc](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-tables2/latest/index.html#linkcolumn-objects)

Hope this helps...