# Django datatable LinkColumn error

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a django datatable using [django_tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html) in one of my templates. One of the column is used to hold links to different pages. Ive been to a lot of questions regarding my issue on SO but cant seem to have any success.

**tables.py**

```
import django_tables2 as tables

from django_tables2.utils import A


class CampaignsTable(tables.Table):
    """docstring for CampaignsTable"""
    id = tables.Column(verbose_name='#')
    name = tables.LinkColumn('ad_sets', verbose_name='Campaign Name', empty_values=())
    # name = tables.Column(verbose_name='Campaign Name')
    objective = tables.Column(verbose_name='Campaign Objective')
    effective_status = tables.Column(verbose_name='Campaign Effective Status')

    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class':'table table-striped table-bordered', 'id':'campaigns'}
        orderable = True
```

From the above Im trying to convert the `Campaign Name` column to a [`LinkColumn`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#linkcolumn) i.e. where each cell is a link resolved as `/ad_accounts/{{ ad_account.id }}/campaigns/{{ campaign.id }}/ad_sets`:

**urls.py** *snippet*

```
url(
    r'^ad_accounts/(?P<ad_account_id>[^/]+)/campaigns/(?P<campaign_id>\d+)/$',
    CampaignDetailView.as_view(),
    name="ad_sets"
```

As suggested in the doc and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942467/1664675) I need to add `args=[A('pk')]` in my `LinkColumn`, but doing that gives me the error

```
ValueError at /ad_accounts/act_1100111250039687/
Failed lookup for key [pk] in <Campaign> {
    "effective_status": "PAUSED",
    "id": "6040446448677",
    "name": "test77",
    "objective": "CANVAS_APP_ENGAGEMENT"
}, when resolving the accessor pk
```

I then tried `args=[A('id')]` which gave me :

```
NoReverseMatch at /ad_accounts/act_1100111250039687/
Reverse for 'ad_sets' with arguments '(u'6040446448677',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Im really confused as to how to go about adding a link in a cell and what exactly the `args=[A('id')]` is doing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

just tried:

```
name = tables.LinkColumn('ad_sets', args=[A('id')], kwargs={'ad_account.id', 'campaign.id'}, verbose_name='Campaign Name',
                             empty_values=())
```

it redirects me to my login page

Comment: did you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157101/django-tables2-linkcolumn-accessor?rq=1)

Comment: I did as soon as I posted my question. However since I not rendering a table from a `model` i dont have a use for the `primary key`, also my URL has 2 variables..